# CocoaPods: Create Pod To Build Multiple Frameworks

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

So, I have developed a Swift iOS/OSX library and I would like to make it available via CocoaPods. There is a portion of the libraries functionality (overloaded operators) that I want to make an explicit opt-in because of how it changes some default Swift semantics. While developing, I achieved this by separating the operator overloads out into a separate framework so that a user would have to do an explicit `import LibraryOperators` in addition to the `import Library` to opt-in to the overloads on a per-file basis. This has worked as expected doing local builds.

My first question is: Does this seem like a reasonable way to provide additional opt-in functionality, or is there a better way? (I wish their was proper namespace creation in Swift!)

Now I am trying to craft a Podspec file to replicate this behavior for users, but I am running into difficulty figuring out how. Specifically, I don't know how to configure the Podspec file to build multiple frameworks. I'm sure I could create the operator overloads as a dependent, but separate, pod, but I would like to avoid users needing to explicitly include both pods in their Podfile.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to achieve this?

Comment: You could create two podspecs, and add the operators as a dependency of the other.  Not sure if others have better suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered carthage as well?  Its easier.

Comment: @Logan I have considered this approach, but would like an approach that doesn't need the user to put additional lines in their Podfile.

Comment: @Jeef I will definitely be adding support via Carthage, but I would like to also make it CocoaPods compatible for folks from that camp and also for discoverability.

Comment: @Logan Just realizing now what you meant and how that would accomplish only needing a single line in a user's Podfile. That might be the best approach available as of now.

Comment: Awesome, hopefully that works!  I think there are other ways, but this is the most straightforward to me.

Comment: @Logan So unfortunately this looks like it won't work because CocoaPods configures build dependencies based on pod dependencies. So because my operators framework has a build dependency on the general library, I cannot reverse the dependency for the pods. It's looking more like the only way forward is to have the user declare both pods in their Podfile.